# Weird Spheres on Character

Tags: 3d-view

I'm just starting out with Blender, and I decided to play around with a pre-provided humanoid model from poly.pizza (https://poly.pizza/m/AZzoJo1FBm).
I imported the model to Blender, but I get all of these weird spheres around the model:[image: polypizza model]

Could anyone explain to me what these are?

Comment: Hello, please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: How did you import the file? - That's a FBX file inside the zip file. If you use Blender's File > Import > FBX (.fbx) menu it imports correctly as a model with animation.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the comments. moonboots, the file will be on the link provided https://poly.pizza/m/AZzoJo1FBm. John, I imported the model from a .glb file format.

Comment: I didn't try the .glb version but as I said the .fbx one works fine so it may be a problem with their .glb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some bizarre reason every bone in the armature has it's custom shape set to the Icosphere in the .glb file, hence the odd display.

[image]

You can unhide this icosphere by checking the monitor icon for the <kbd>glTF_not_exported</kbd> collection in the <kbd>Outliner</kbd>.

[image]

Then select the <kbd>Icosphere</kbd> entry and hit <kbd>X</kbd> while the cursor is over the Outliner to delete it. That will also delete all the custom shapes as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help John! I switched to the .fbx file as you mentioned, but I came back to the .glb to try this out, and it works.

Comment: Good! No idea why it was created like that. - The FBX one wasn't!  Incidentally you can also delete the 'glTF_not_exported' collection in the Outliner to tidy up but just deleting that will not delete the Icosphere. You will need to delete both.